# nodejs - Mongoose 5.3.8 - GeoJSON queries not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, 2dsphere, mongodb-geospatial

I am attempting to store and query locations based on coordinate points with Mongoose 5.3.8 in order to **return points within the radius of another point**.
I have read the docs and have implemented the pointSchema + citySchema example in the section:
[Using GeoJSON data](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) seen below

```
const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
  }
});

const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: {
    type: pointSchema,
    required: true
  }
});
```

with an [express](https://expressjs.com/) endpoint, I query an mLab instance with the following code and a document stored as:

```
DOCUMENT ---------------------------

{
    "_id": "5bdbeb78949541086880dd35",
    "name": "Location1",
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [
            48.5,
            -123.8
        ],
        "_id": "5bdbeb78949541086880dd36",
        "type": "Point"
    }
}

QUERY --------------------------------

Location.findOne({
   location: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: coordinates // [long, latt]
       },
       $maxDistance: 10000,
       $minDistance: 1
     }
    }
  }).then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

---

The above query caught the error:

```
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

I attempted to add an index on the LocationSchema by calling .index()

```
LocationSchema.index({ "location": "2dsphere" });
```

I also attempted to add an index to the Schema by:

```
LocationSchema.index({ category: 1, location: "2dsphere" });
```

no index was created on the schema and the error persisted.

---

I have attempted several other Schema/Query combinations including:

1. [Mongoose geospatial search: distance not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251872/mongoose-geospatial-search-distance-not-working) - Feb 7, 2016
2. [Mongoose Geospatial Queries with $near](https://medium.com/@galford151/mongoose-geospatial-queries-with-near-59800b79c0f6) - April 10, 2018
3. [unable to find index for $geoNear query #6549](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6549) - May 31, 2018
4. [Net Ninja's GeoJSON tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvY8vcrojYw) - March 27, 2017

---

I have gotten none of them to **return points within the radius of another point** despite using nearby coordinates to query. I don't understand where this is going wrong.

- Is there a working example of a geospatial query that can **return points within the radius of another point** in mongoose 5.3.8?

edit: clarified question

**EDIT:**

Got it to work.
In the mongoose options connecting to the mLab instance my options were as followed:

```
    const mongoOptions = {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoIndex: false,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  reconnectInterval: 500,
  poolSize: 10,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
};
```

The `autoIndex: false` parameter made it so that no new indexes could be created, even when specifying `LocationSchema.index({ "location": "2dsphere" });`.
To fix this I had to add `LocationSchema.options.autoIndex = true;` for some reason. Hope this might help someone.

Comment: You should have tried the post from 2013. The key is `type: { type: String }` to avoid the confusion between mongoose's `type` schema definition keyword and `type` in GeoJSON. Nonetheless the question here simply has not shown any schema definition showing what you actually tried. Hence the suggestion to follow an existing and correct answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn If you check in the first paragraph, I state the schema design that I used and give reference to it in the first link. If you check the link: [unable to find index for $geoNear query #6549](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6549) in my also attempted list, the schema design matches the `type: {type: String}` logic. Yet this design returns nothing with the query. I have edited the question to provide clarification on the first schema I attempted. Thanks for the help.